# How to check blank input field validation using Python and Django

Tags: python, django, validation

I need to validate fields if they are blank at the time of form submit. My code is below:

bmr.html:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'some' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>location name: </label>
    <input name="lname" maxlength="250">
    <br>
    <label>Room name: </label>
    <input name="rname" maxlength="250">
    <br>
    <label>No of Seats: </label>
    <input type="number" name="seat" maxlength="10">
    <br>
    <label>Projector Screen</label>
    <select name="projector">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label>Video conference</label>
    <select name="video">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

the python side code is given below.

```
def some(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serch=request.POST.get('searchby')
        location_name = request.POST.get('lname')
        rname = request.POST.get('rname')
        seat = request.POST.get('seat')
        projector = request.POST.get('projector')
        video = request.POST.get('video')
        num=str(random.randint(100000000000,999999999999))
        location_name = location_name[0:255]
        rname = rname[0:255]
        seat = seat[0:10]       
        doc = m.parse("roomlist.xml")
        root=doc.getElementsByTagName("roomlist")
        valeurs = doc.getElementsByTagName("roomlist")[0]
        element = doc.createElement("location")
        element.setAttribute("name"  , location_name)
        el1 = element.appendChild(doc.createElement("room"))
        el1.setAttribute("id", num)
        el2=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("roomname"))
        el2.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(rname))
        el3=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("noseats"))
        el3.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(seat))
        el4=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("projectorscreen"))
        el4.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(projector))
        el5=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("videoconf"))
        el5.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(video))
        valeurs.appendChild(element)
        doc.writexml(open("roomlist.xml","w"))
    return render(request, 'booking/bmr.html', {})
```

Here I need if any field is blank it will show user the validation message and the form will not submit.

Comment: Why aren't you using the Django forms framework? This is exactly what it's for.

Comment: In this case what to do. Can i use javascript ?

Comment: What? I just told you what to do. Why did you bring JavaScript into this? Use a [Django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/).

Answer (score 1):

In **Javascript** you can validate, for example here

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function validateForm() {
    var a = document.forms["Form"]["lname"].value;
    var b = document.forms["Form"]["rname"].value;
    var c = document.forms["Form"]["seat"].value;
    var d = document.forms["Form"]["projector"].value;
    if (a == null || a == "", b == null || b == "", c == null || c == "", d == null || d == "") {
      alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>



<form method="post" action="{% url 'some' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>location name: </label>
    <input name="lname" maxlength="250">
    <br>
    <label>Room name: </label>
    <input name="rname" maxlength="250">
    <br>
    <label>No of Seats: </label>
    <input type="number" name="seat" maxlength="10">
    <br>
    <label>Projector Screen</label>
    <select name="projector">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label>Video conference</label>
    <select name="video">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
</form>
```

OR
you can add **required** attribut to input fields in your django **Form widget**

```
class YourForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field_name'].required = True
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the required attribute in the input fields and let the html do the work for you.

```
<input name="lname" maxlength="250" required>
....
....
```

and also if  you want to do a validation at the server side just do this

```
serch=request.POST.get('searchby')
location_name = request.POST.get('lname')
if search == "" or location_name == "" ... :
   messages.error(request, 'Please fill all the fields")
else: 
    num=str(random.randint(100000000000,999999999999))
    location_name = location_name[0:255]
    rname = rname[0:255]
    seat = seat[0:10]       
    doc = m.parse("roomlist.xml")
    ....
    ....
```

but the best method to do validations is to use django forms it will save time to you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Django forms instead of Javascript.
First time, you have to create a models file :

```
class YourModel(models.Model) :

    yourfield = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, ...)
```

The argument `blank=True` let to get blank field.
Then you can use forms file according to your models.